# Detecting "Phonegap Developer App"

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using phonegap/cordova and using "phonegap developer app" for testing. Since there are some operations that are not supported by "phonegap developer app" (e.g. external plugins) I wonder if there is a way to detect that the app is running on "phonegap dev app"?

For this particular case I want to switch between "web db", if running on "phonegap app", and "sqlite", if running on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to detect feature availability via JS. The plugin's API won't be available, and so you can check for its existence to determine if you should fall back.

```
if (window.sqlite) {
   // plugin is available
} else {
   // plugin is not available
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Steve Kennedy answer I have reached the following solution that is working:

```
if (typeof window.sqlite !== 'undefined')
    {
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db", createFromLocation: 1});  // tries to use prepopulated database
        console.log("--> running on device");
    }
    else
    {
        db = window.openDatabase("my.db","1.0","Demo",-1);          // var "db" is declared on amob_db.js
        console.log("--> running on Phonegap Developer App");
    }
```